# Regex for Markdown Emphasis

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match the following markdown text for emphasis:

```
_this should match_
__this shouldn't__
_ neither should this _
_nor this _
this _should match_as well_
__       (double underscore, shouldn't match)
```

The issue that I'm facing with my own efforts as well as other solutions on SO is that they still end up matching the third line:

> `_ neither should this _`

Is there a way to check of my particular use case? I'm aiming this for browser applications, and since [Firefox and Safari are yet to support lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind), is there a way to do this without lookbehinds?

Here's the regex pattern that I've come up with so far: `/(_)((?!\1|\s).*)?\1/`

Luckily, I'm able to fulfil almost all of my checks, however my pattern still matches:

```
_nor this _
__       (double underscore, shouldn't match)
```

So, is there a way to ensure that there is atleast *one* character between the underscores, and that they are not separated from the text by a space?

Link to regexr playground: [regexr.com/5300j](https://regexr.com/5300j)

Example:

```js
const regex = /(_)((?!\1|\s).*)?\1/gm;
const str = `_this should match_
__this shouldn't__
_ neither should this _
_nor this _
this _should match_as well_
__
_ neither should this _`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try `text = text.replace(/(^|[^_])_(?![_\s])((?:.*?[^_\s])?)_(?!_)/g, '$1<em>$2</em>')`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLjJZY/1)

Comment: @Andreas my bad, added one. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for `this _should match_as well_`, it only matches `_should match_` :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew modified your regex a bit, and it works! `/(?:^|[^_])_(?![_\s])((?:.*[^_\s]))_(?!_|[^\s])/gm`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZ9mxG/1)

Comment: No, I am not sure it is correct, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZ9mxG/2), what if there is a string like `this _should match_as well_ and this_should_match_ too`?

Comment: Ah snap, you're right. I edited it a bit more [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZZ9mxG/3), and its already much better than what I had started with. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Then it means you can simplify it much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use either of

```
\b_(?![_\s])(.*?[^_\s])_\b
\b_(?![_\s])(.*?[^_\s])_(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/htoULc/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - no word char (letter, digit, `_`) allowed immediately before the match
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?![_\s])` - no `_` or whitespace chars are allowed immediately after `_`
- `(.*?[^_\s])`  - Group 1:

  - `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `[^_\s]` - any 1 char other than `_` and whitespace
- `_`  - an underscore
- `\b` - no word char allowed immediately after the `_`.

Note that `(?!\S)` fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location and acts as a right-hand whitespace boundary.