# Regex for Markdown Emphasis with asterisks * and underscores _

Tags: javascript, regex

NOT A DUPLICATE OF [Regex for Markdown Emphasis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346949/regex-for-markdown-emphasis)

but an upgrade.
The perfect regex posted into the answer covers only the case with underscores but Markdown support also asterisks.

TLTR: I need a regex to match markdown emphasis with `_em_` and `*em*`

- Not spaces before and after (`_`| `*`) both at beginning end ending of the match
- Not double (`_`|`*`) at beginning at ending
- No different start-end like `*foo_`

My attemp to solve the problem is

```
\b[_\*](?![_\*\s])(.*?[^_\*\s])[_\*]\b
```

But doesn't cover the perfectly the case with `*`

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/geSz7z/2) is an example with some tests. Should match only the `_em_` and `*em*` cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
/([_*])(?<!(?:\1|\w).)(?![_*\s])(.*?[^_*\s])(?=\1)([_*])(?!\w|\3)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/geSz7z/3). *Details*:

- `([_*])` - Group 1: `_` or `*`
- `(?<!(?:\1|\w).)` - a negative lookbehind: no same char as in Group 1 or any word char and then any char immediately to the  left of the current location
- `(?![_*\s])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `_`, `*` or whitespace immediately to the right of the current location
- `(.*?[^_*\s])` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then a char other than `_`, `*` or whitespace
- `(?=\1)` - a positive lookahead that requires the same value as in Group 1 to be present immediately to the right of the current location
- `([_*])` - Group 3: a `_` or `*`
- `(?!\w|\3)` - not immediately followed with a word char or same value as in Group 3.